# Which occasion does trigger GC in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm trying to learn how Parallel GC works and now I'm reading this [***article***](https://plumbr.eu/handbook/garbage-collection-algorithms-implementations#parallel-minor-gc):

Trying it myself I found the following line:

```
[GC (GCLocker Initiated GC) [PSYoungGen: 4000739K->93296K(4034048K)] 
5488394K->1629174K(6578176K), 0.0492402 secs] 
[Times: user=0.40 sys=0.00, real=0.05 secs]
```

It means the minor GC was triggered. But the reason was not allocation faulire? So what was actually the cause of that GC? Is it possible to turn it off?

Comment: Too broad. Different type of garbage collecters will use different heuristics, different strategies.

Comment: This is parallel GC

Answer (score 1):

Your YoungGen is  full:

```
[PSYoungGen: 4000739K->93296K(4034048K)]
```

It means that it's size is 4034048K, and 4000739K was allocated. The size of allocated space after Minor GC becomes 93296K.